# Malayalam text goes out of view in TextView, in some smaller screen sizes. (No issues with English text)

Tags: android, character-encoding, localization, textview, word-wrap

I have an application which fetches malayalam text from an RSS feed.

For the sake of brevity, I will use a simple app with static text to explain my problem.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView=(TextView) (findViewById(R.id.textview1));

        String text=" സഭ പരിശുദ്ധമാണെന്ന് വിശ്വാസപ്രമാണത്തിൽ നാം പ്രഘോഷിക്കുന്നു. എന്നാൽ, സഭ പാപികളുടെ ഒരു കൂട്ടായ്മയാണെന്നും, എല്ലാ ദിവസവും ഞങ്ങൾ അവരുടെ പ്രവൃത്തികൾ  കാണുന്നതാണെന്നും നിങ്ങൾ പറഞ്ഞേക്കാം. സഭയിൽ പാപികൾ ഉണ്ടെണ്ടന്നത് സത്യമാണ്. ";
        textView.setText(text);
    }
```

First of all, when I try to save this file with that malayalam text, I get this Message:

[image]

I save as UTF-8 and move on. Note that in my actual app, this does not happen, since the text is downloaded.

Here is the pretty basic xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
 >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the text view does not wrap text properly (at the ends). This happens only in some screen sizes. Otherwise, its fine.

This thing does not happen with english text.

I have tried singleline, ellipsize,different paddings etc..nothing works.

I feel like this has something to do with encoding, but no Idea what.

Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Comment: Do you got any solution? I am also struggling for my app which uses Tamil font.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a bug with Android itself: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38357 .

It seems to be fixed in 4.2.
I got around it by using a webview instead of a textview, for pre 4.2 devices. The webview rendering is not perfect, but better than the text getting cut off.